# Sniffing with tshark/wireshark via ssh and double sudo

Tags: ssh, cygwin, wireshark, sudo

## Situation

- My laptop with wireshark/tshark and cygwin
- remote machine available via ssh. On this host I have personal ssh account . On this account I can sudo to other account. On other account I can call tcpdump via sudo. So pseudo script looks like:

  ```
  ssh myAccount@remoteHost
  sudo su - otherAccount
  sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i any -n -U -s 0 -w - port 1234
  ```

## Problem

I want pipe output from tcpdump to tshark, but I have error.

## What I tried

### Try 1

In cygwin I called

```
ssh -tt  myAccount@remoteHost 'sudo su - otherAccount <<EOF
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i any -n -U -s 0 -w - port 1234
EOF' | /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Wireshark/tshark.exe -i -
```

but I got the following message:

```
Capturing on 'Standard input'
tshark: Error reading from pipe: Operacja ukoĹ"czona pomyĹ>lnie.
 (error 0)

0 packets captured
Connection to remoteHost closed.
```

### Try 2

```
ssh -tt  myAccount@remoteHost 'sudo su - otherAccount <<EOF
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i any -n -U -s 0 -w - port 1234
EOF'
tcpdump: WARNING: Promiscuous mode not supported on the "any" device
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
```

I see some output from tcpdump eg. SIP. Exactly at the terminal appears:

```
s
▒ò▒ ♦         ▒▒  q   iV▒W\▒♣ 4  4      ♠▒_▒▒m▒  E $b}@ ▒◄▒▒
O}
Oi▒V▒►COPTIONS sip:remoteHost SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP otherSipHost:57430;branch=z9hG4bKe05fb9ab6ddd10690707
Max-Forwards: 70
To: sip:remoteHost
```

Thanks in advance

Krzysiek

Comment: Does work if instead of a Windows program like shark you use a cygwin one like tail ?

Comment: @matzeri   I describe it in "Try 2"